# jquery Autocomplete not working in a master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to use jquery auto complete in my master page but its not working.Please help me to solve this issue.I have a textbox as search box on top of my master page where i want auto complete to occur.But master page function getProductList is never called.

My autocomplete code is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $(".tb").autocomplete({
             source: function (request, response) {
                 $.ajax({
                     url: "MasterPage.master/getProductList",
                     data: "{ 'keyword': '" + request.term + "' }",
                     dataType: "json",
                     type: "POST",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                     success: function (data) {
                         response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                             return {
                                 value: item.Name
                             }
                         }))
                     },
                     error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                         alert(textStatus);
                     }
                 });
             },
             minLength: 1
         });
     });
</script>


  <asp:TextBox  class="tb" id="appendedInput"   placeholder="Search" runat ="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

code in code behind of master page is like this:

```
  [WebMethod ]
    public  ProductList[]getProductList(string keyword)
    {
        List<ProductList> Products = new List<ProductList>();
     DataSet    _ds = new DataSet();
        ProductsBAL pbl = new ProductsBAL(0);
        pbl.Search(_ds, URLMessage.GetParam("Keyword", "").ToString());

        foreach (DataRow dr in _ds.Tables[pbl.SqlEntityX].Rows)
        {
            ProductList prolist = new ProductList();
            prolist.Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            Products.Add(prolist);



        }

        return Products.ToArray();


    }

    public class ProductList
    {
       public  string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes got it... need to put the code behind code of master page into some content page. and then call that from master page like index.aspx/getautomcompletelist.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are calling incorrect URL in $.ajax.

You have to call your .aspx page through "getProductList" method

url: "MasterPage.aspx/getProductList"

Comment: thx but Still not working @Rachit

Comment: did you receive any data or your call success event?

Comment: no its not calling this function..Now I pasted this web method in my index.aspx code behind and changed my url: "index.aspx/getProductList" but its not calling there also.

Comment: could you please put break point in your web method and debug this?

Comment: I did that but its not going there .I mean web method is never called.thx

Comment: Is my code correct , I dont have much experience with jquery

Comment: code looks fine however you can refer this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/63e78b/call-an-Asp-Net-C-Sharp-method-web-method-using-jquery/  hope this article will help you

Comment: I suggest, you start with simple way first after that add complexity in your code like. first call simple method without parameter, once you start getting data after that pass parameter and error handling.

Comment: Got the missing thing I wasnot including script files:<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>...but now method is called but it is showing undefined errorthrown.